# Power BI : why EARLIER() does not recognize date column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to make a cumulative measure in Power BI as Following :

```
prices = SUM(Testing[price])

comulativetest = CALCULATE([prices],FILTER(Testing,EARLIER(Testing[Date])>=Testing[Date]))
```

but this error message appear to me 
[image]

and this is the table
[image]

what's the problem with it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier is mostly used in the context of "calculated columns". I think you are trying to use it in a measure and that's why you are getting an error.

Create a "Dates" table, and create a (one-to-many) join between that and your "Testing" table. Then use a measure like this:

```
comulativetest :=
CALCULATE (
    [prices],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Dates ),
        Dates[Date] <= MAX ( Dates[Date] )
    )
)
```

Comment: it also workes for me without new table as following :comulativetest2 = CALCULATE ( [prices], FILTER ( ALL ( Testing ), Testing[Date] <= MAX ( Testing[Date] ) ) )

Comment: You are welcome. I'm happy that it worked. It's always a best practice to use dates from a separate Dates table, otherwise, you might get some strange results from DAX ;)